# How to view all fields with more than 3 tables laravel

Tags: laravel

Hi there can someone please help me I am new on laravel I have this three tables:

**Table 1. users**

> 'first_name', 'last_name', 'bio', 'image', 'email', 'password',
>   'user_group','remember_token',

**Table 2. professions**

> 'id', 'title',

**Table 3 user_profesions**

> 'id','user_id', 'profession_id'

How can I take all this fields and show than on view 
I started something on Controller like this:

```
 public function index(){


        $mentors = User::where('user_group', 2)->get();



        return view('mentors.list-of-mentors')->with(['mentors'=>$mentors]); 
    }
```

But this is  only takes from table mentors I want to be able to send to the view the fields with users  that have more than one profession

Answer (score 3):

Try below
Also make sure your UserProfession model has belongsTo relation with User and Profession

UserProfession.php model

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
}

public function profession()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Profession::class, 'profession_id');
}
```

Your code

```
UserProfession::with('user', 'profession')
    ->whereHas('user', function ($q) {
        $q->where('user_group', 2);
    })
->get();
```